# Does mongodb C# driver make server call to get database?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am using mongodb c# driver v2.7.3.

I would like to know if `client.GetDatabase()` statement makes a call to mongodb server or not?

```
IMongoClient client = this.dbConnection.client;
var db = client.GetDatabase(databaseName);
```

Does it internally goes to the mongod shell and run `use db` command ?

I have many concurrent requests to get the instance of `IMongoDatabase`. If the driver is making a server call then it would be good if I cache the instance to improve performance.

Looking at the source code, it does not seem that it is making a server call. 
But how can I confirm ?

[Mongo Db Source Gitlab](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver/MongoDatabaseImpl.cs)

Answer (score 2):

If you refer to the Mongo C# Driver references, you'll see a couple of notes.

### MongoClient Re-Use

> It is recommended to store a MongoClient instance in a global place, either as a static variable or in an IoC container with a singleton lifetime.
>   However, multiple MongoClient instances created with the same settings will utilize the same connection pools underneath. Unfortunately, certain types of settings are not able to be compared for equality. For instance, the ClusterConfigurator property is a delegate and only its address is known for comparison. If you wish to construct multiple MongoClients, ensure that your delegates are all using the same address if the intent is to share connection pools.

### IMongoDatabase Re-use

> The implementation of IMongoDatabase provided by a MongoClient is thread-safe and is safe to be stored globally or in an IoC container.

For more info about storing instances and other use cases, you can look at http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.9/reference/driver/connecting/

Answer (score 1):

Until you interact with the MongoClient or the IMongoDatabase instance the connection is not actually established or validated. If you will be using a singleton to store your client instance a test similar to the following could be used:

```
try
{
  _client = new MongoClient(settings);
  _database = _client.GetDatabase(db.DatabaseName);
  _database.RunCommand((Command<BsonDocument>)"{ping:1}");  
}
catch
{
  // there is a problem with the settings do not store
}
```

The above sends a ping command which can be used to test if the server is responding to commands. It will also force the connection to be established via the MongoClient and ensure the connection is valid as a result.